# Knowledge of religion without Language?

Tags: quran, islamic-philosophy, language, metaphysical

I was having a discussion with this person about religion.
He asked me that whether it would be possible for human beings to have the concept of God without having the knowledge of Language.

I pondered over it and realized that we could not recognize anything if we don't have language.

For this concept, I recalled few verses from the Qur'an:

> 1.)  And [mention, O Muhammad], when your Lord said to the angels, "Indeed, I will make upon the earth a successive authority." They
>   said, "Will You place upon it one who causes corruption therein and
>   sheds blood, while we declare Your praise and sanctify You?" Allah
>   said, "Indeed, I know that which you do not know." **And He taught
>   Adam the names - all of them.** Then He showed them to the angels and
>   said, "Inform Me of the names of these, if you are truthful." They
>   said, "Exalted are You; we have no knowledge except what You have
>   taught us. Indeed, it is You who is the Knowing, the Wise."
>
> -Qur'an 2:30-32
>
> 2.)
>
> The Most Merciful.Taught the Qur'an,Created man,**[And] taught him
>   eloquence.**
>
> -Qur'an 55:1-4

So the fact that Allah(SWT) mentioned teaching us language right after our creation implies that there is some truth in what he said.

My question is is there any paper, thesis or any article that deals with this concept. Or any other source that could help me to understand this concept.

And show that person, so that he might be convinced that Islam is the true Religion.

Sincere Thanks in Advance,
Jazakallaho Khairan

Comment: Salaam! I don't know about your taste for philosophy but there's a very substantial philosophical concept that have been treated within different philosophical schools (including Islamic) which generally postulates human speech and intellect to be integral and a manifestation of a cosmic reality named Logos. See 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logos

Answer (score -1):

I have looked into this issue quite a lot. First I thought, I should be human to know God. Then I thought, no it is not necessary, even if I am an animal, cat or dog, I would still know God, then I thought, no even if I am plant or tree, I would know God, then I thought, no even if I am non-living thing like Mountain, Stone, Sun, Star, I would know God. But finally, I concluded, that I even don't need to be existed to know God. One of God's name is Az-Zahir, that He is so Manifest that you don't even need to be existing to know Him. Isn't it so weird? Subhan Allah :)